# Postgres: how to create overloaded function that returns setof type

Tags: postgresql, function

I have defined a function:

```
create or replace function get_matches(_mia match_input[])
returns setof contact_index
```

I want to create an overloaded version of this function which will accept a single match_input object:

```
create or replace function get_matches(_mi match_input)
returns setof contact_index
as $func$
begin
  select get_matches(array[_mi]);
end
$func$
language plpgsql strict;
```

It compiles fine, but I get this error when I run it:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a PL/pgSQL function you need to use [return query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

```
create or replace function get_matches(_mi match_input)
  returns setof contact_index
as $func$
begin
  return query select get_matches(array[_mi]);
end
$func$
language plpgsql 
strict;
```

alternatively use a SQL function instead:

```
create or replace function get_matches(_mi match_input)
  returns setof contact_index
as $func$
  select get_matches(array[_mi]);
$func$
language sql 
strict;
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly... I have a related follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249408/postgres-how-to-overload-functions-having-single-record-type-input-parameter